# Getting JSON String with streaming GSON with ByteArrayOutputStream gets OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, crash, gson, out-of-memory, outputstream

This is my code:

```
@Nullable
private static String streamBlaModelsIntoJsonString(List<BlaModel> blaModels) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        writer.setIndent("  ");
        writer.beginArray();
        for (BlaModel blaModel : blaModels) {
            gson.toJson(blaModel, BlaModel.class, writer);
        }
        writer.endArray();
        writer.close();

        return out.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And this is crash report from Fabric:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1219838 byte allocation with 265632 free bytes and 255KB until OOM
   at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:176)
   at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:59)
   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:232)
   at com.example.magnificentapp.util.SharedPrefsUtils.streamBlaModelsIntoJsonString(SharedPrefsUtils.java:230)
   at com.example.magnificentapp.util.SharedPrefsUtils.saveBlaList(SharedPrefsUtils.java:207)
   at com.example.magnificentapp.BlaListActivity.goToDetail(BlaListActivity.java:462)
   at com.example.magnificentapp.presentation.view.activity.BlaListActivity.onItemClick(BlaListActivity.java:605)
   at com.example.magnificentapp.adapter.viewholder.BlaViewHolder$2.onClick(BlaViewHolder.kt:34)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

The crash happens on the line `return out.toString("UTF-8");`. This code was written to fix `OutOfMemory` crash in my application but I still got the error more than I had been getting before.

I tried to stream BlaModels one bye one and append with a StringBuilder, but it seems consuming more memory.

I cannot reproduce the crash but this crash report is the flagship among all crashes in my Fabric.

I need more advancement for my code, but I am doing my best. Someone gotta get top of it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close **ByteArrayOutputStream** try this after you done with **out** instance

```
if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not an Android expert, but the exception is clearly telling you that it cannot handle large strings.
Dealing with large strings is problematic even for desktop/enterprise Java and is usually considered an anti-pattern if used without a good reason.
I *guess*, you have at least two ways of dealing with it:

- do real streaming and write the real JSON to elsewhere not buffering into an intermediate string;
- do a sort of lazy mapping and store every list element separately (I've peeked into the stacktrace and found `SharedPrefsUtils` that most-likely indicates the use of a key-value storage).

If you're fine with the first approach and you wish to write to a storage, then it's all very simple:

```java
// Gson instances can be reused and you can save time and memory just having it as a static field
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
// Let speed it up by caching the reference to the type adapter
private static final TypeAdapter<BlaModel> blaModelTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(BlaModel.class);

private static void stream(final Iterable<? extends BlaModel> blaModels, final Writer writer) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer);
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    for ( final BlaModel blaModel : blaModels ) {
        blaModelTypeAdapter.write(jsonWriter, blaModel);
    }
    jsonWriter.endArray();
}
```

If you still have to use strings (as far as I see, the shared preferences editor cannot work with streams), you can convert the list elements one by one lazily and let the caller code decide when and what to do.
I'm not sure if it can hold a big amount of data within one transaction, but if it doesn't, you might probably want (again, I'm not an Android expert) to commit the preferences more frequently or write the JSON documents to a storage and just put the paths as the values (a sort of symlinks).

```java
private static Iterable<String> mapBlaModels(final Iterable<BlaModel> blaModels) {
    return new Iterable<String>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                private final Iterator<? extends BlaModel> iterator = blaModels.iterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterator.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public String next() {
                    final BlaModel blaModel = iterator.next();
                    return blaModelTypeAdapter.toJson(blaModel);
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Or if you're using Google Guava:

```java
private static Iterable<String> mapBlaModels(final Iterable<? extends BlaModel> blaModels) {
    // Or even Iterables.transform(blaModels, blaModelTypeAdapter::toJson); when using RetroLambda
    return Iterables.transform(blaModels, new Function<BlaModel, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(@Nullable final BlaModel blaModel) {
            return blaModelTypeAdapter.toJson(blaModel);
        }
    });
}
```

And then

```java
final Iterable<BlaModel> blaModels = ImmutableList.of(new BlaModel(), new BlaModel(), new BlaModel());
final Iterable<String> jsonDocuments = mapBlaModels(blaModels);
final Iterator<String> jsonDocumentIterator = jsonDocuments.iterator();
for ( int i = 0; jsonDocumentIterator.hasNext(); i++ ) {
    final String jsonDocument = jsonDocumentIterator.next();
    // TODO manage the document index and the JSON document
    // Say, something like putString("blaModel:" + i, jsonDocument), etc
}
```

This would require a bit more efforts making some breaking changes to your shared preferences structure, but this would save the memory and wouldn't run into out-of-memory issues caused by intermediate strings.

Hope this helps.